# Store procedure executing only once inside a while loop in java

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, while-loop, callable-statement

I am using below code to execute one store procedure inside a while loop which has two records

```
 conn = this.pool.getConnection();//backgroundtask.getDBConnection(this.config).getConnection();
 conn.setAutoCommit(false);
 TimezoneUsers = conn.prepareStatement(getUserTimeZone);
 TimezoneRs = TimezoneUsers.executeQuery();
 while (TimezoneRs.next()) {
     int TimeZoneId = TimezoneRs.getInt("Id");
     int CurrentHour = TimezoneRs.getInt("UserHour");
     try (CallableStatement upperProc = conn.prepareCall("{call \"CreatePersonGameHistoryWithTimezone\"(?) }")) {
          upperProc.setInt(1, TimeZoneId);
          upperProc.executeQuery(); 
  }
```

After while loop i am able to print TimeZoneId 248 and 419
but only first call stored stocedure successfully executing where as call with 419 is not successfull

Note:this is called in a multithreaded environment

Comment: Can you define "is not successful" - was anything logged, any exception? Can you add a try/catch block?

Comment: @vikingsteve  this store procedure suppose to update one table for that TimeZoneId. for 248 its perfectly working where as for 419 its not.I am not getting any error or warning.Yes i have try/catch block

Comment: Do you have any logging on the database side? Can you see if the call is actually being made? Otherwise, `upperProc.executeQuery();` should return a `ResultSet` - can you assign it to a variable and examine it?

Comment: Lastly did you try `.execute()` instead of `executeQuery` ?

Comment: @vikingsteve yes i tried .execute() and tried to print boolean value both gives me true after execute. but this sp doesnt return anything.Do you find anything wrong in my code?

Comment: In your code you set `setAutoCommit(false)` - do you flush/commit your updates anywhere?

Comment: @NiklasP yes i have commit code after all my execution.

Comment: @deadpool +1 for the cool name & photo ;)

Comment: did you commit after the first sp? can you show the code that does the commit?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the cause of the problem, but can you try to move the instantiation of the `CallableStatement` above the `while` loop? The same prepared statement should be re-used within the while loop.